# prestashop free shipping issue

Tags: prestashop, cart

I just upgraded firstly manually but later on by 1-click Upgradev1.0.13 to 1.5.4 version. I got a big problem on shopping cart with the shipping fees.
The cart located on homepage top left was solve not to show "FREE SHIPPING" from the previous code in this forum.
But once I checked on the shopping cart inside after I select and press "Update Carrier List" button and
press "Update Cart" button, the shipping fees is not updated but show as "FREE SHIPPING".

Could anyone suggest me solution about this? Thank you very much. I very much appreciate it.

My demo website is http://store.relishthai.com/.
You can try to add item by selecting the "TEA" tag and add one item to the cart and see the "FREE SHIPPING" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very similar issue. The problem is that there is a Javascript file that updates the value to "FREE SHIPPING" if the value(shipping price) is equal to 0.00. I am using a different version, so I can't exactly point you to the file, but you can definitely solve this in three minutes. (Check order-opc.js in your theme/js folder)

View source of the web page and see what .js files are included. Search "FREE SHIPPING" in Javascript files (such as cart.js) and see which one is the culprit. Then go on FTP and change it to 0.00. I prefer "Free!" by the way ;)

EDIT: It seems like I misread your Q.
I tried pressing "Update carrier list" and then "Update cart", but I do not see the shipping fees as "Free shipping." Instead, I see 8 dollars.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jay Na. I'll try it. As I remember in version 1.5.3.1, I can set the shipping fee to be updated in the cart but might not for guests. Now, I have more problem with shipping fees in 1.5.4 version. So I'm kind of hesitated if I should roll back, or use another less problem version or should consider walk away from pestashop because I have been spent a long time to fix things.

Comment: I am still not sure what problem you are having with shipping. At first, I interpreted the question as "I want to change 'free shipping' to '0.00.' " Then, I re-interpreted your question as "there is a bug where shipping fee just becomes zero"? My answer above is for the first case. I coul not replicate the second case at all.

Comment: Hi Jay Na, let me try to check again then. Previously, the cart on top left of homepage showed shipping fee as $0.00 but now shows only the handling fees but not include shipping fees from carrier.

Comment: Many many thanks, Jay Na. Let me double check all again. And capture screens. Thanks tons for your help :))

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether one cause might be from adding zone without fees added so the program detecting $0.00 from the empty zone. Once I deleted the cart updates the price but I need to check all again. Let me get back to you again whether all are solve. Thank you very much. Very appreciate your help :))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again. Previously before your answer the $0.00 appeared in the top left cart on the page but later on after your comments I double checked things and deleted unused zone (no fees in there). And I tried to put the real shipping fees for all weight ranges. Now, the old problems has been solved but the shipping fees with weight ranges (in small ranges) still exits. I'll try to figure things out. 
Many Thanks!!

Comment: Hi I checked your shop and it seems the problem is solved now! I have the same problem maybe you could help me on this

Comment: Hi Behrang,
I'm not sure what problem you have. If you already update the destination countries which you will ship products and the weight range. Everything will be fine. It's been a long time and I forget many things. One thing I still do remember that the range is a bit tricky. At the beginning, I use grams for the measurement but some said it's not stable. So I change grams to kilograms but I still have a problem showing not correct fees or Free shipping. So I solved the problem by entering the range like

0kg to 0.5005 kg
0.501 kg to 1.005 kg

Comment: Because if I use 0kg to **0.500 kg**, the prestashop code will not display correctly. But my programmer friend said this can solved by editing the code. For other issue about showing Free Shipping, I paid a programmer to help coding since I'm only a merchant.

Hope I answer you a question.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file /themes/xxx/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl
and remove this block of code (or comment):

```
<div class="layer_cart_row">
    <strong class="dark">
        {l s='Total shipping' mod='blockcart'}&nbsp;{if $display_tax_label}{if $priceDisplay == 1}{l s='(tax excl.)' mod='blockcart'}{else}{l s='(tax incl.)' mod='blockcart'}{/if}{/if}
    </strong>
    <span class="ajax_cart_shipping_cost">
        {if $shipping_cost_float == 0}
            {l s='Free shipping!' mod='blockcart'}
        {else}
            {$shipping_cost}
        {/if}
    </span>
</div>
```